# Change the order of filter in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth in my web application. The third party which I get calls from, unfortunately is sending UUID in the X-B3-TraceId header. But the TraceFilter in spring could sleuth errors out because of the '-' characters in the UUID when converting from string to hex. SO I decided to write my own filter which will intercept the request before the TraceFilter and remove the trace id from the header. This is my configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean getZipkinFilterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        bean.setFilter(new ZipkinHeaderReplaceFilter());
        bean.setOrder(1);
        bean.addUrlPatterns("/");
        return bean;
    }
```

And this is the TraceFilter from spring-cloud-sleuth:

```
@Order(TraceFilter.ORDER)
public class TraceFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    protected static final int ORDER = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 5;
    .........
}
```

So the order of the trace filter is exactly `-2147483643` and I think this makes it appear before my filter. I dont want to change the order of my filter. How do I change the order of `TraceFilter` to `2` since the `TraceFilter` is automatically registered by spring boot auto configuration?

Comment: why not register TraceFilter  with FilterRegistrationBean  and set order?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detail of [spring boot filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners),It says:

> If convention-based mapping is not flexible enough you can use the `ServletRegistrationBean`, `FilterRegistrationBean` and `ServletListenerRegistrationBean` classes for complete control.

I believe you can change the order in those classes.The order of filter are same as you add (filter to your config class) order in config class.

Comment: TraceFilter is not under my control. Its form the library.